# Copy data from one workbook to new workbook and save them by specific title

Tags: database, excel, copy-paste, vba

I have one file which is database and contain data of all student from different classes. I want excel to make class wise files by copying data from database to new file... I am using below mention codes and these are working perfect but it only coping data till Column G and now data has extended to Column Z and its not working give me run time error.

"Note Column B tittle Class" i.e Tittle of new saved file

```
Sub proSaveDateClasswise()

Range("I1").Value = "Class"
Columns("B:B").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copyToRange:=Columns( _
    "I:I"), unique:=True
Range("J1").Value = "Class"

Dim cell As Range
Dim curPath As String

curPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Extracted Files\\"

If Len(Dir(curPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir (curPath)
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each cell In Range("I:I")
    If cell.Value <> "Branch" And cell.Value <> "" Then
        Range("J2").Value = cell.Value
        Range("A:G").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            criteriarange:=Range("J1:J2"), copyToRange:=Range("L:R"), unique:=False
        Range(Range("L1:R1"), Range("L1:R1").End(xlDown)).Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=curPath & cell.Value & ".xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWindow.Close
        Range(Range("L1:R1"), Range("L1:R1").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
    End If
Next cell

Columns("I:R").Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue here before we go any further is that your current macro uses some columns beyond G in order to select unique classes. That means the whole code would have to be rewritten for it to work as you expect. I suggest you provide some input and output files with dummy data to work on.

Comment: yes i can give demo file but dont know how to share/upload file here... if you see coding its copy Range("A:G") is it possible if i can replace G by Z so more column can be added ???